# How to exit Select-String after 100 matches found?

Tags: powershell, select-string

Is it possbilbe to exit Select-String after 100 matches so that it does not have to read until the end of the text file?

I want to get a sample of matches that is only first 100 matches.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Assuming you use PS v3+: `Select-Object -First 100`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  You probably could use a Do-Until loop or a for loop and increment a counter then break the loop once you reach the desired number.

```
$q = Get-Content 'C:\docs\qqq.txt'

$q | Select-String -Pattern "(Patching)" | Select -first 100
```